# What time was question asked

Tags: support, questions, answers, user-interface

How do I find the time that a question was asked?

I am looking at a question that is labelled as asked yesterday.
The exact time, may be of relevance in answering the question.

The question is: [Unable to change time-zone properly, the time is still from the previous time-zone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297577/4778)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hover your mouse over the time shown (the words "asked yesterday" in your example, "asked two days ago" in the screenshot below) in the box with the name of the asker of any question and the time will show as a pop-up.

[image: screenshot showing the time popup]

The pop-up might show up differently in different browsers. In Chrome on OSX, for example it shows up as white for me. The above screenshot, @terdon added to this post, shows it as black background.

[image]

And just so it's clear, you have to hover directly over the time the question was asked to see this (#1 in the 2nd screenshot).

Comment: Thanks, it works. In addition I note that I have to point the top of my I beam at the text, and then wait for it to appear.